# Compare the excel and database data by highlight difference changes or data between them

Tags: php, excel, laravel

```
if (Input::file('import_file')) {
        $reader = \Excel::load(Input::file('import_file'))->toArray();
        return View::make('preview',compact('reader'));
    }
```

I am using maatwebsite to import excel data to database.

Before that, i want to show the changes in a simple table by comparing both excel and database data and highlight the different between them.

I wish to show changes on excel data before update to database.

Is that possible to do that?

Comment: You can, heres how I would do it: 1. Get the excel content to your $reader as array, like you did.    2.  Get the database information that you require, into an array.     3. Depending on your result, you can validate the query result based off some index or some field, or you can take both arrays and do work with http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Comment: Is it a good solution to do that? I think it will be heavy for the server right?

Comment: I believe so, but wouldn't be heavy for the server, unless the excel file is big. I've had performance issues using maatwebsite but its due to xlsx files, I'm working with php csv reader and its a lot faster. You got to have data if you want to compare something, so fetching the data isn't the question. Your question should be, what is the best performance technique I can use to have the result that I want. Is it comparing $reader to $databaseResult ? is it using $reader values to query your database search? It all depends on your final purpose